# Pass a range as an argument in a formula using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really REALLY new using VBA, so I apologize for this question in advance:

Basically, I'm trying to write a sub that will calculate IRR on a range of numbers that is dynamic. So I tried to create a variable which would select the range of numbers, and then using a named range for the output cell(IRR), have the result of the formula show. Below is the code I have:

```
Sub irrCalc()

Dim calcrange As Range


Set calcrange = Range("B55").End(xlToRight).Select


Range("IRR").Formula = "IRR(calcrange)"


End Sub
```

The error I'm getting is 'Object required', and its pointing to the center line of code "Set calcrange".

I have been looking for an answer but I can't seem to find (or understand) what the problem is...Again I know this is probably ridiculously easy but I'm a bit stumped. Thanks in advance

Comment: remove `.Select` from end of statement. And why apologize for questions when you are learning? For more information the `.Select` will actually select a cell. When you Set a variable value, selecting the range is not necessary (and it actually breaks the code as you can see).

Comment: Thanks, Scott. So I can run it now without an error, but the output in the cell is showing up as "IRR(calcrange)". Any idea why that would happen & how to get it to caluclate? Thanks,

Comment: Try "= IRR(calcrange)".  OR give me the number of columns to calculate and I'll give you the VBA to calculate them.

Comment: `calcrange` is seen as a string literal because you've enclosed it in quotes. That variable only exists in the execution context of the VBA code - Excel knows nothing about it. `"IIR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"` would *concatenate* the *address* of the `calcrange` object into the string literal, which is probably what you're looking for. Also IIRC a formula needs to start with `=`.

Comment: @ Mat's Mug-yes that fixed it. Thanks to you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be sure. But maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
Sub irrCalc()

Dim calcrange As Range

Set calcrange = Range(Range("B55"), Range("B55").End(xlToRight))

Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate it. The concatenation in the IRR formula was what I was missing. I appreciate the time you guys spent helping out, it made my life much easier! And I also learned today.

Comment: @jules325 Also note, the change in the range: `Range("B55")` is not really a range as it consists of only one cell. To get a *real* range you need a starting point and an end point: `Range(startHere, endHere)`. `Range("B55")` is the starting point end `Range("B55").End(xlToRight)` is the end point `-->` giving you a range of cells to pass to the `IRR()` formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("IRR").Formula = "IRR(calcrange)"
```

-You are putting a formula into the cell requesting it to run a named range through a subroutine called "IRR".

Setting the range in a module does not make it a named range.  You need the following code to do that:

```
Set rng1 = Range("B55:B200") ' How many columns need to be calculated
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="calcrange", RefersTo:=Rng1
```

Now you have a named range to work with.

Do you have a subroutine "IRR" to work with?  It looks like you are referring to a single cell named "IRR."  It's confusing and probably erroneous to use the same name for different things like ranges and functions or subroutines.  Can you post your subroutine "IRR?"